# Db-migrate on Postgresql 9.4.5 on Heroku gives SSL errors

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I've got a NodeJS project on Heroku that uses a Postgres 9.3.9 database. I'm trying to upgrade to Postgres 9.4.5, so I created a 9.4.5 database in my staging environment and tried to run my migrations on it, but I keep getting SSL errors. Here's a log of a migration attempt (note that username and database have been redacted):

```
$ ../node_modules/db-migrate/bin/db-migrate --verbose up --env staging
[INFO] Using staging settings: { driver: 'pg',
  user: '<username>',
  host: 'ec2-54-83-29-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: '5432',
  database: '<dbname>',
  password: '******',
  sslmode: 'require',
  native: true }
[INFO] require: ./pg
[INFO] connecting
[INFO] connected
[SQL] select version() as version
[ERROR] Error: SSL error: point is not on curve
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "12.251.228.138", user    "<username>", database "<dbname>", SSL off

    at Error (native)
```

This same setup works fine with my Postgres 9.3.9 database.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I think I just hit the same problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened in my case (I had the exact same error).

I was trying to connect to a Heroku PG 9.4 instance. Locally I had installed both 9.5 (via homebrew) and 9.5 (via [postgresapp.com](http://postgresapp.com/), and my ruby driver (pg) was relying on `pg_config` from 9.3 (`--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`)

Removing my local installations (in particular 9.3) then reinstalling locally postgresapp v9.4, then rebuilding my local library against 9.4, solved the connection issue completely.